# Compact a data frame by removing some of the NA cells?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply, na

If I have a data frame as follows:

```
data.frame(
  cola = c(3,NA,NA),
  colb = c(1,NA,NA),
  colc = c(NA,6,NA),
  cold = c(NA,7,NA),
  cole = c(NA,3,NA),
  colf = c(NA,NA,9), 
  colg = c(NA,NA,8)
)
```

How can I shift all fields to the left, eliminating NA values as needed, as here:

```
data.frame(
  cola = c(3,6,9),
  colb = c(1,7,8),
  colc = c(NA,3,NA)
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to shift fields to the left, then it's more of a (transposed) `matrix` than a `data.frame`.

Comment: Maybe `which(!is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)` can lead to smth interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We loop through the rows, remove the `NA` elements with `na.omit` and then append `NA` at the end based on the max length of the `list`

```
lst <- apply(df1, 1, na.omit)
out <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst)))))
```

Comment: What about an one-liner: `data.frame(t(apply(dfa, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][seq_len(max(rowSums(!is.na(dfa))))])))`?

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% rownames_to_column() %>%
    gather(measure, value, -rowname) %>%
    group_by(rowname) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    mutate(measure = paste0("col", row_number())) %>%
    spread(measure, value) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-rowname)
#    col1  col2  col3
# 1     3     1    NA
# 2     6     7     3
# 3     9     8    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose, drop NAs, transpose back:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

DF %>% transpose %>% lapply(na.omit) %>% transpose %>% 
  data.frame %>% setNames(names(DF)[seq_along(.)])

  cola colb colc
1    3    1   NA
2    6    7    3
3    9    8   NA
```