# How to transform/simplify a data.frame with timeseries in columns to an "indexed" shorter version?

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, xts, zoo

How do I go from image #1 to #2 in R ?

I would expect this transformation to be so common in timeseries analysis that **xts::**, **zoo::** or **data.table::** would have a pre-built routine to make the series "indexed" (note the Index in red in the second image) automagically with a one-liner.

I can manually do this looping/**apply**-ing over the columns but want to learn if there is a pre-baked solution to this (expectedly very common) dataframe transformation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697761/compact-a-data-frame-by-removing-some-of-the-na-cells) is somewhat similar. The upvoted solution uses a rather  intricate

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst)))))
```

that I would like to avoid.

**Image #1:**

[image: Image 1:]

**Image #2:**

[image: Image 2:]

Image 1

sample data.frame as requested:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), to=as.Date("2010-02-15"), by=1),
                 `2008/09` = c(rnorm(10), rep(NA,36)),
                 `2009/10` = c(rep(NA, 3),  rnorm(10), rep(NA, 33)),
                 `2010/11` = c(rep(NA, 5),  rnorm(10), rep(NA, 31)),
                 `2011/12` = c(rep(NA, 10), rnorm(11), rep(NA, 25))
                 )
```

Comment: You could melt, create the index, then dcast back

Comment: I don't think there is a prebaked function to do just what you want, though, since it violates a notion of `data.frame` where values within a row are for a single observation; by shifting things around like that, the observation-based assumption is dismissed. That's not to say that it isn't a useful feature, just that it isn't "baked in".

Comment: However, that code expression there would have to be the _second_. The _first_ expression would need to remove leading `NA` values, which would leave them as ragged columns (not eligible for `data.frame`); after that removal, we'd need this second step to restore the "same lengths" notion of the frame.

Comment: Valid question, but... Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. At least post your input data as code. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment  and suggestions @M-- .  I have added code for a the input/sample dataset. Can you please reopen the question?

Comment: Would you explain the difference between this question and the dupe-target? I apologize if I have missed anything, but to me it seems that you want to put the NAs at the bottom of each column.

Comment: @M-- Is this definitely a duplicate? The data here are 36-month cohorts starting May, e.g. May 2008-April 2011 for cohort 2008/2009. If there are NA's _within_ the 36 months, `lapply(.SD, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))` won't give the right result.

Comment: It's not a perfect dupe, but it's really close. Possibles: (1) pivot/repivot: `pivot_longer(df, cols=-Date) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% mutate(Index=row_number(), .by=name) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols=Index, names_from=name, values_from=value)`. (2) Base R "shift": `fun <- function(z) \`length<-\`(z[cumsum(!is.na(z)) > 0], length(z)); df[] <- lapply(df[,-1], fun) |> transform(Date=NULL, Index=seq.int(nrow(df)))`, though that is likely too "intricate"?

Comment: Dan, one problem with your supposition that it is "so common" is this isn't just a reshaping of columns in an array, since often the axes indicate a clear time basis (e.g., year). When you shift a column to remove leading-`NA`, the left-axis time-period is broken, which not-insignificantly requires remapping of "time" in the data. If there were a common function for this, I suspect it would likely trigger "inadvertent data corruption" for many people due to misuse, and I personally feel that dismissing the time component like this is not a normal thing. My two cents. Good luck!

Comment: In your second image you have indices not dates, so you could just drop the dates before using the solution in the dupe-target and then convert rownames to an id column. If you want the dates, as r2evans explained, then you don't have a dataframe per se; one thing you could do is to add one date column for each of the value columns and proceed like that.

Comment: OK but repeating that the dupe-target "shifting NAs to the bottom" will give a _silent wrong answer_ if we have holes in the data, e.g. `df <- data.frame(Date=seq(2010, 2014), "2011"=c(NA,1,1,1,NA), "2012"=c(NA,NA,1,NA,1))`. The line `mutate(Index=row_number(), .by=name)` needs to be replaced by `mutate(Index=Date-as.integer(sub("X", "", name))+1)` or similar date difference logic.

Comment: @Dan, your instinct is not wrong in that rebasing from calendar time to "analysis time" (or cohort age) _is_ a common and sometimes canned operation in e.g. survival analysis, but using long not wide data. With long data you can have both kinds of time in two columns.